# TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'object'

Tags: typescript

i am writing a object with typescript, the code is:

```js
const obj2 ={name:1}
obj2.name = 2;
console.log(obj2.name)
const obj3:object = {name: "wewda"}
obj3.name = 'dadsa';
obj3['name'] = "cxzcxz"
console.log(typeof obj2)
console.log(obj3)
console.log(typeof obj3)
```

I got an error in line 5:  error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'object'.
but if i use `obj3['name'] = "cxzcxz"` instead,
it works, can anyone explain? thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
const obj3:object = {name: "wewda"};
```

You've explicitly declared that `obj3` is of type `object`, effectively discarding any information about what properties the object can contain. The type `object`, by the way, is a type that represents the non-primitive type, i.e. anything that is not `number`, `string`, `boolean`, `symbol`, `null`, or `undefined`.

So there's no way that the type system can verify that `obj3.name` is valid. However, if you're running with the default compiler options (which are rather lax), `obj3['name']` will be allowed because `obj3` will be implicitly cast to `any`, even though in principle it's equally unsafe. I generally recommended that you enable the `--noImplicitAny` compiler option to guard against this kind of unsafe access.

Note also that this is a compile-time error in your typings, not a run-time error. In other words, the *value* of `obj3` still has the property `name`, but the *type* `object` does not.

Comment: You might want to also answer the other part of the question about why `obj3['name']` works, which is because it uses indexed access, which is implicitly allowed and typed as `any`.  The best way to deal with this is to turn on the `--strict` (or at least `--noImplicitAny`) compiler option so that you get an error there too.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for your comment. I was stumbling over how to phrase that clearly.

Comment: thank you all! when I enable the noImplicitAny option, I got two compile errors:types.ts(37,6): error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'object'.
types.ts(38,1): error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature.